# Framework7 does not support onPageInit method in php pages?

Tags: javascript

I am using framewokr7 on a project, and this would use the onPageInit method to a page that appears in the form of popup. Follows the main source for these actions:

myApp.onPageInit ('popup', function (page) {console.log ('Contacts page initialized');});

```
$$('.create-popup').on('click', function () {
$$.ajax({
    url      : 'popup.html',
    data     : false,
    method   : 'GET',
    complete : function(data) {
      myApp.popup(data.responseText);
    }
}); });
```

However, this way does not work ... It's like he did not recognize the

```
<div data-page="popup" class="page">
```

Html ...

Any tips?